# Word for Mac keeps converting PDF figures to bitmap

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, pdf, office-for-mac

I have a PDF file that I need to use as a figure in a Word document.  I can insert the PDF without problems, and I can export the document as a PDF from Word, retaining all details in the figure.

But if I save the document as standard `.docx`, close it, then later re-open it, the figure gets converted to a low-resolution bitmap image, and the vector data is permanently lost.  This happens only with certain PDF figures, not all of them.

Is there a workaround?  Does anyone know what property of the PDF is causing this to happen, so I can try to avoid it?

The behaviour is the same in Word 2011 and in Word 15.26 for Mac.

---

Note that Word for Windows works differently. *This question is specifically about the Mac version.*  [Linked objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) are a Windows-specific feature and do not apply to the Mac version, which supports PDF directly, without the need for third party software such as Acrobat.

---

[This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38623/foo.pdf) is an example of a "bad" PDF file that triggers the problem (created for the purpose of demonstration).  Steps to reproduce the problem: Create a new Word file, then drag and drop the PDF into it.  It will render in high resolution, and it will be resizable.  Now save the file, close it, and reopen it.  Now it is rasterized at low resolution, and even worse, it has JPEG compression artefacts.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How did you insert the PDF in the Word document. As picture, as object ?

Comment: @Tonny Drag and drop, which I assumed to be the same as Insert -> Picture.  I now tried both Insert -> Picture and Insert -> Object with the exact same result.  What's the difference?

Comment: Picture and object can be quite different, depending on the actual type of the inserted file. E.g.: On the Windows version of Word PDF is always object, not a picture. I don't have a Mac here. I see if I can reproduce the behavior later when I'm at home.

Comment: @Tonny I strongly suspect that the Windows version is significantly different.  PDF is sort of a native format for Macs as [the OS X graphics API mirrors how PDF works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)#Use_of_PDF).  Even stuff copied to the clipboard is typically PDF (where it would be EMF on Windows).  PDF has been natively supported by Mac Office for a long time.

Comment: I'm well aware of that, but how the details work out exactly isn't something I will hazard a guess at without trying some things myself first.

Comment: @Tonny It only happens with a few PDFs I have, it doesn't happen with most.  I cannot post that PDF because it's not my property.  It's not a corrupted file, it can be opened with various PDF viewers, and re-processing through tools like ghostscript, mupdf, multivalent, Mac Preview, or even Illustrator doesn't make the problem go away.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in Word 2011. Has to be some property of the PDF file itself that causes this.

Comment: I'm on Windows, but for what's worth, the only way I managed to get the document into Word was by Inserting it as an Object of a format for which I have an installed server. In my case I used "Adobe Acrobat PDFXML Document". Maybe you should not just drop it into the document, but use a compatible Object format. Does Word for Mac have Insert Object?

Comment: @harrymc No, that functionality is specific to Windows.  PDF is natively supported on Mac.

Comment: This seems logical, as Mac Office doesn't have OLE objects. You might try to convert the pdf to another vector format that is better supported (maybe EMF if it exists), or even replace it by a high-resolution image.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, that's the obvious thing, but it won't work in my case. EMF doesn't exist on Mac and even if it did, it just can't handle the required complexity. The figures *need* to be kept in PDF too, separately from the Word document, so converting them is an extra step. I need to periodically update the figures and put them in a Word file, which also contains captions and also gets edited by others.  Additionally I need to produce a PDF from it. In practice this means that every time there's a figure update, I need to re-insert *every single figure* just to be able to produce a proper PDF.

Comment: @harrymc Now if it were up to me I would never touch MS Word with a ten foot pole.  LaTeX is just so much more convenient.  But it happens that I am required to use Word despite all the inconvenience it gives me.  At this point however I really don't believe there's a good solution to this problem ...

Comment: Another idea might be to use latex, then generate a format acceptable to Word. Various solutions exists (see [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111886/how-to-convert-a-scientific-manuscript-from-latex-to-word-using-pandoc)), but more can be found via google including commercial products ([example](http://grindeq.com/index.php?p=word2latex&lang=en)).

Comment: Sadly, I'm having the exact same problem in Word for Mac 16.78 (2023).